# Пунктуация в предложении (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Где необходимо поставить запятые?
обреченный на погибель я скитался по миру в надежде увидеть тебя

Answer (score 1):

[Обречённый](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/36696/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — в данном предложении это причастие (страд., прош., от *обречь*).
*Обречённый на погибель* — причастный оборот (причастие + зависимое слово).

1. Причастный оборот обособляется независимо от его места в предложении, если он относится к личному местоимению (***я***, ты, мы, вы, он, она, оно, они).
2. Предложение должно начинаться с заглавной (большой) буквы и заканчиваться точкой.

***Обреченный на погибель,*** я скитался по миру в надежде увидеть тебя.

[Обособление согласованных определений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/714-233_obosoblenie_soglasovannyh_opredelenii.html)